# Why does devise parameter sanitizer permit sign_up instead of user_registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # Permit the `subscribe_newsletter` parameter along with the other
    # sign up parameters.
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:subscribe_newsletter])
  end
end
```

Why is the first parameter here sign_up?

when typing `rails routes`,

I see

```
                new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
               edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
                    user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                                      PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                                      DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                                      POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
```

I'd assume user_registration (for the POST)instead:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:user_registration, keys: [:subscribe_newsletter])
```

I think there should be some logic in devise mapping sign_up to use_registration.

I can locate the permit function:

```
def permit(action, keys: nil, except: nil, &block)
  if block_given?
    @permitted[action] = block
  end

  if keys.present?
    @permitted[action] ||= @auth_keys.dup
    @permitted[action].concat(keys)
  end

  if except.present?
    @permitted[action] ||= @auth_keys.dup
    @permitted[action] = @permitted[action] - except
  end
end
```

How to continue tracing from here?

Answer (score 0):

It's just what they are called, no mapping here:

```rb
DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES = {
  sign_in: [:password, :remember_me],
  sign_up: [:password, :password_confirmation],
  account_update: [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
}
```

*https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.8.1/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L38*

Notice that [permit](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.8.1/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L110) method doesn't actually permit anything, it's just building a hash, and it's letting you add your own parameters.

Actual parameter [permission](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.8.1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L137) is happening in [sanitize](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.8.1/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L70) method, where attributes held in `sign_up` are used to permit `params` submitted by the form, which are scoped to `user`. Something like this:

```rb
# params         = {"user"=>{"email"=>"email", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
# device_mapping = :user
# permitted      = DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES

params[device_mapping].permit(permitted[:sign_up])
```